# Using Fiddler2 / Charles in PHP

Tags: php, fiddler, charles-proxy

How can `Fiddler2` be used in an automated fashion inside of a PHP web service to capture request headers and send them to other parts of my PHP code? I found out the fact that it can be automated inside PHP (http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-PHP) but I couldn't find an implementation. `Charles` seems easier and more obvious to get up an running for this task using the web interface but Fiddler2 is free of course. Any additional links or info would be very helpful.

Also, I see these are primarily debugging tools but is there a reason one would advice using them in production code for scale and thousands of requests per minute?

Comment: What exactly would you need Fiddler for that PHP can't already do for you? Incoming request headers are in [`$_SERVER`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) or, more conveniently, [`apache_request_headers()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php) if your server runs PHP as an Apache module. Do I misunderstand?

Comment: These tools give more information about incoming API traffic. I need information about the traffic flow from a link on **website A** to my **PHP script** . Website A has jQuery links to API. I see this information in the application UI but I'm not sure how to list this out in my PHP code. I want to create a situation where the external user clicks the link and information about the traffic flow is processed and the session closed. Are these even the right tools for this kind of job? Basically I think I want a web service implementation of FireBug that can be used by many concurrent users.

Comment: Can you give some examples about what information you think these tools can give you that PHP can't? What do you need to know about an incoming request? Have you tried `var_dump()`ing the things I mentioned in my first comment to see if that information is in there?